# PHCachingImageManager.requestImage is always called twice?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, phasset, xcode9

I have a `UICollectionView` with a custom `UICollectionViewCell` that should get and display thumbnail (low quality) photos from the Photo (usually the user can select more than 1 photo) in each `UIImageView` in the cell.

I've been playing with the `PHImageRequestOptions` and their properties, reading about them. To a point that I even passed `nil` as a parameter for `requestImage(for: PHAsset)` method because I'm not sure where I'm wrong.

The problem is that the `requestImage(for: PHAsset)` method is called twice. I need the first time that it's called to just to set the image in each collection view cell with the low quality (thumbnail image) and once the full size image is ready, it should be added in an image array called `assetsTurnedIntoImages`. The problem is that I'm doing something wrong and I always get the `if` and the `else` method called twice, so basically, if I've selected 4 images from the Camera Roll (hence, I have 4 images in the assets array) and when they go through the requestImage(for: asset) method I get 8 images in the `assetsTurnedIntoImages` instead of 4. So Here's my code

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        print("Assets count is:", assets.count)
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PhotoPostCVCell", for: indexPath) as! PhotoPostCVCell
        if let takenImage = cameraPhotoUIImage
        {
            cell.cellImage.image = takenImage
        }
        if assets.count > 0
        {
            let asset = assets[indexPath.row]

//            var imageRequestOptions: PHImageRequestOptions
//            {
//                let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
//                //options.version = .current
//                //options.resizeMode = .exact
//                //options.deliveryMode = .fastFormat
//                options.isSynchronous = true
//                return options
//            }
            let targetSize = CGSize(width: asset.pixelWidth, height: asset.pixelHeight)
            imageManager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: targetSize, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: nil)
            { (image, info) in
                if image != nil
                {
                    let imageQualityState = info![PHImageResultIsDegradedKey] as! Bool

                    if imageQualityState
                    {
                        print("LOW QUALITY")
                        print("Image Quality State is:", imageQualityState)
                        cell.cellImage.image = image
                        print(image!.size)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        print(image!.size)
                        cell.cellImage.image = image
                        self.assetsTurnedIntoImages.append(image!)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Affraid there is not much you can do about `requestImage:forAsset` being called twice. However, you can change how you are putting images in the array to avoid duplicates. Might I suggest:

```
self.assetsTurnedIntoImages[indexPath.row] = image
```

This will cause the image passed into completion the second time around to replace the one that was called the first time, avoiding duplication.

You will want to pre-initialize enough space for your array ahead of time so that `indexPath.row` does not try to access your array out of bounds.
In `ViewDidLoad` add something to the effect of:

```
self.assetsTurnedIntoImages = [UIImage](repeating: UIImage(), count: assets.count)
```

Comment: I get a crash though. I get  an error  `fatal error: Array index is out of range`

Comment: hmmm they must not be getting called in order, lets say the `requestImage` gets called at image 3 before it does at image 1. I will update my answer.

Comment: I did as you suggested, but the `assetsTurnedIntoImages ` now has triple the amounts of images in it. If I have picked 4 assess from Photos, I get 12 images in the array.

Comment: Do you have 12 assets? What is `assets.count` in `ViewDidLoad`?

Comment: No, it's 4. This is why it's so baffling. I don't get why they've tripled now.

Comment: Changed answer, we should assign the image at said index instead of insert. My apologies.

Comment: OMG, this actually worked. I've been struggling with this for a week! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 9):

You can discard those low-res duplicates by including this conditional:

```
imageManager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: targetSize, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: nil) { (image, info) in

let isDegraded = (info?[PHImageResultIsDegradedKey] as? Bool) ?? false
if isDegraded {
   return
}
```